# Выбрать максимльно количество записей

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Никак не могу реализовать такой запрос: необходимо вывести **id** пользователя, у которого максимальное количество друзей.
Есть такая таблица:

```
user_one    user_two    type
5           6           1
6           5           1
12          6           1
7           34          1
34          7           1
12          7           2
34          7           2
```

Когда делаю так, все ок:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted
        FROM `friends`
        WHERE `type`='1' AND `user_two`='6'
        OR `type`='1' AND `user_one`='6'
```

Но я хочу сделать так, чтобы был подсчет всех записей для отдельных пользователей и выведено максимальное их количество. То есть, так чтобы мне вывело **id** пользователя(он может быть и **user_one** и **user_two**. то есть с этими полями разница в том,что они показывают кто отправил запрос) у которого `type=1`. Надеюсь понятно объяснил, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ну отсортируй по убыванию количества и возьми первую запись, делов-то...

Comment: НУ это понятно, но а как это сделать? Я пробовал вот так: SELECT MAX(counted)
                                FROM
                                (
                                SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted
                                FROM `friends` WHERE `type`='1'
                                GROUP BY `user_one`
                                ) as counts Но не получается

Comment: У 7 пользователя сколько друзей с type=1 ? Правильно - 2. значит надо отдельно посчитать записи где он в первом поле и где во втором. значит нам надо каждую запись в таблице посчитать 2 раза, сначала для одного, затем для другого. итого что то вроде `select user,count(1) from (select user_one as user from tab union all select user_two from tab) X order by count(1) desc limit 1`

Comment: Ну, Ваш запрос неправильный, получается так, что дальше первой строки я не продвигаюсь

Comment: Но вы же хотели "максимальное количество", вот он и дал именно одну строку с этим самым максимальным. И никто не сказал, что вам кто то должен дать правильный запрос. Я указал направление. Модифицируйте запрос под свои нужды. например уберите limit 1 что бы давал количества по всем пользователям

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select user_ -- , cnt
from (
  select user_, count(*) as cnt 
  from (
    select user_, user_two from(
      select user_one as user_, user_two from friends where type = 1
      union all
      select user_two, user_one from friends where type = 1
    ) as t
    group by user_, user_two) as t
  group by user_) as t
order by cnt desc, user_ asc
limit 1
```

Comment: Мне нужно вывести id пользователя, у которого максимальное количество друзей(type=1 а само id может быть как user_one так и user_two). Так понятно? Просто Ваш запрос показывает количество всех строк. И вывожу я все это так:
$biggest_funbase_username = mysql_query("SELECT user, count(*) from (select user_one as user from friends where type = 1 union all select user_two from friends where type = 1) X group by user") or die(mysql_error());
 $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($biggest_funbase_username);
 echo "User-".$result['user'];

Comment: Хорошо. Что должно быть выведено для пользователя "6" ? Согласно Вашего второго запроса в постановке выведется 3. Это правильно? Мне кажется, что нет. Т.к. у пользователя "6" только 2 друга: 5 и 12.

Comment: Да, верно, должно быть два друга. И должно вывести id пользователя , к которого больше всего друзей(6 либо 7 так как у них по одинаковому количеству друзей).В случае, если бы у пользователя 6 было 3 друга, вывело бы только id пользователя под номером 6. Еще я пытался сделат так,но выдает ошибку: SELECT MAX(counted)
FROM
 (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted
   FROM `friends`
   GROUP BY `user_one`,`user_two` union all
 ) as counts

Comment: Давайте разберёмся подробнее. В случае, когда у 6 и 7 пользователя совпадает максимальное количество друзей, кого нужно вывести: обоих или первого из списка, допустим, отсортированного по айдишнику?

Comment: И ещё, при подсчёте друзей мы не обращаем внимание на type?

Comment: Если одинаковое количество вывести первого по id . Нет, как раз таки внимание на type обращаем(так как если type=1, то данные пользователи друзья, если type=2 то запрос отклонен и они не друзья).

Comment: Я сейчас отредактирую свой ответ. Попробуйте.

Comment: Ошибка, и cnt разве не должно быть AS cnt? И еще, у меня стоит  MySQL версии 5.5.25 может ли быть в этом проблема?

Comment: Я под оракл писал. У меня нет MySQL, к сожалению. Попробуйте "as cnt"

Comment: Ну просто в том то и дело что оба варианта не работают

Comment: MySQL не поддерживает CTE (Common Table Expressions). Вы запускайте запрос без with... . В with... я, можно сказать, сгенерил Вашу таблицу friends.

Comment: Все равно не получается реализовать запрос

Comment: А что за ошибка хоть?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by 0) max_friends from ( select user_, count(*) AS cnt ' at line 3

Comment: Попробуйте теперь запсутить (без with).

Comment: без with тоже не работает

Comment: Поправил. Пробуйте.

Comment: Шикарно! Все работает, спасибо!